# How to add 'routerlink' in ionic toast

Tags: angular, ionic4

Using ionic toast the "routerlink" attribute in a anchor tag gets removed from the message.

The href attribute will not get removed but ends up disrupting the routing stack.

```
this.toastController.create({
message: '<a routerLink="some/link">some text</a>'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use button and use an handler. Then use navCtrl to navigate**

```
buttons: [
        {
          side: 'start',
          icon: 'star',
          text: 'Favorite',
          handler: () => {
            this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/path')
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, but the message has to contain the link. It's added via L10n, there shouldn't be any further coding.

Comment: And there is no navCtrl in ionic4 anymore!